# MYSQL Duplicate Key Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

Why is my `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement not working,  I am after a way to not have duplicates in my table.  With the below code I get duplicates

```
CMS::insertQuery("INSERT INTO {table} SET canid=?, categoryid=? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE canid=?, categoryid=?", array($emailCheck['id'], $id, $emailCheck['id'], $id));
```

**DB:**

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (  `canid` int(10) NOT NULL,  `categoryid` int(10) NOT NULL,  UNIQUE KEY `canid` (`canid`,`categoryid`)) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**Current Line I am trying to run:**

```
CMS::insertQuery("INSERT INTO {table} SET canid=?, categoryid=? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE canid=?, categoryid=? WHERE canid=?, categoryid=?", array($emailCheck['id'], $id, $emailCheck['id'], $id,$emailCheck['id'],$id));
```

Comment: Do you have a unique composite key on canid and categoryid?

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` only executes the update part if the insert would violate a unique key.  Without a unique key, there is nothing to check for duplicates.  And my first comment isn't correct as I meant it; as long as a unique key would be violated on either column, not necessarily both, the `UPDATE` would be executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a guess since you haven't provided your schema, but is one of the columns in your unique key nullable?

**Edit:**

As @G-Nugget says in the comments, you need a unique key on the columns in question:

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that
>   would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, MySQL
>   performs an UPDATE of the old row.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

You need to have a unique key on the combination of columns that should be unique.

eg:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD UNIQUE KEY (`canid`, `categoryid`);
```

Also, when asking database questions, please include `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables in question.

Comment: I dont think I have a unique key and I am unsure if I should set one as many ids can have the same catid

Comment: @JessMcKenzie If you only want there to be one combination of canid and categoryid, you should use a unique composite index on both columns.

Comment: @G-Nugget but I can't add a UNQUIE id for the table as there will be more then one `canid` but the `canid` should have one `categoryid` per row but other `canid` can have the same `categoryid`

Comment: @G-Nugget This is my current table structure and I am `canid 11` and I have the `categorys 761` when I do an update I do not want 761 to duplicate I want any new values that have been selected to insert http://d.pr/i/8A9G

Comment: @JessMcKenzie if you specify multiple columns in a UNIQUE key (like my example above), it does what you want - you can't have a duplicate of BOTH `canid` and `categoryid`.

Comment: @therefromhere When I run ur example I get #1064 - You have an error  'ADD UNIQUE KEY `canid`, `categoryid`' at line 1

Comment: @therefromhere Is this correct? http://d.pr/i/z3oY  Is there anything I have to do to my php statement?

Comment: Sorry, I missed out the table name bit.  Edited my post, but still untested.

Comment: @JessMcKenzie yes, that's what I meant.  But please, post you schema as text not as an image.

Comment: @therefromhere I have updated the question with the DB Schema and the line that I am trying to run

Answer (score 0):

First thing to note, the field on which you would like to check for duplicate should be primary or unique. I was having the same issue and solved now.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html