# MySQL Insert Into and on Duplicate Key query is not updating

Tags: mysql, sql

My table before the insert (Table name is ds_answer)

```
===============================================================================

answer_id  |   member_id  |  question_id | msgstr | type  |        tstamp

===============================================================================
   50            2             176          aaaa     show   2014-07-27 12:11:12
   51            2             177          bbbb     show   2014-07-27 12:12:23
   52            2             180          cccc     show   2014-07-27 12:12:50
===============================================================================
```

Query command ::

```
INSERT INTO `ds_answer` (`member_id`, `question_id` , `msgstr` , `type`)
  VALUES ('2', '180' , 'dddssds' , 'show' )
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE msgstr = 'dddssds'
```

It's not working.  MySQL added row every time. But It isn't update `msgstr` column in answer_id = 52.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Which columns have unique indexes?

Comment: do you actually have a unique index to trigger the `on duplicate` stuff? `insert ... on duplicate` doesn't check if there actually is a unique index. it'll try the insert no matter what, but the on dupe stuff just won't ever trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to work, there has to be a unique key (index) to trigger it. Create a unique key on the column or columns that should trigger the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Going by your sample insert statement, it seems like you want a multi-column unique index on: `(member_id, question_id)`.

Something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE ds_answer
  ADD UNIQUE INDEX `ui_member_question` (member_id, question_id);
```

Comment: My guess is he needs a unique composite index on `(member_id, question_id)` -- show the command for adding this.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. this answer is help me ^^

Answer (score 0):

As @therefromhere says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539757/mysql-duplicate-key-not-working).

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, MySQL performs an UPDATE of the old row.

You need to use a unique key to make it work

Have a look at the documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html